# What is the probability that the first to arrive has to wait as least 12 minutes?

Tags: probability

a man invites his fiancee to the mall for sunday brunch. They decide to meet at the mcdonalds aisle between $11:30$ AM ant $12$ noon. If they arrive at random times during this period, what is the probability that the fist to arrive has to wait at least 12 minutes?

### Try

Let $X$ be arrival time of man and $Y$ the arrival time of fiancee. We have that both $X,Y$ are uniform on $(0,30)$. We know $|Y-X|$ is the amount of time either one has to wait. So we need to find $P(|Y-X|>12)$. The joint density is $f_{XY} = \frac{1}{900}$ by independence on the the rv where $x,y \in [0,30]$. So, we have to find

$$ P(Y-X > 12) + P(Y-X < -12 ) $$

Lets, find P(Y-X>12), we hae

$$ P(Y-X >12 ) = \int\limits_{12}^{30} \int\limits_{0}^{x+12} \frac{1}{900} dydx= \int_{12}^{30} \frac{x+12}{900} dx = \frac{1}{900} (x^2/2+12x)_{12}^{30} = \frac{594}{900} $$

Is this the correct solution?

Comment: That doesn't seem like it can possibly be right. How did you get the probability that $Y-X>12$ is greater than one half.

Comment: I mean the idea is right, but your integration can't possibly be right

Comment: Oh your bounds are wrong. The inner integral should go from $y=x+12$ to $y=30$. and $x$ should go from $0$ to $30-12$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jgon stated the correct limits of integration in the comments.

The problem can be interpreted geometrically as follows:  Let $X$ be the number of minutes he arrives after 11:30 am; let $Y$ be the number of minutes his fiancee arrives after 11:30 am.  The entire region is a $30 \times 30$ square.  If his fiancee arrives more than $12$ minutes after he does, then the point $(X, Y)$ representing their arrival times lies in the shaded triangle at upper left in the diagram below, which is bounded by the lines $X = 0$, $X = 18$, and the line $Y = X + 12$.  If he arrives more than $12$ minutes after his fiancee, then the point representing their arrival times lies in the shaded triangle at lower right in the diagram below, which is bound by the lines $Y = 0$, $Y = 18$, and $Y = X - 12$.

[image: arrival_times]

Thus, the probability that one of them arrives more than $12$ minutes after the other is found by dividing the area of the two shaded regions by the area of the square, which is 
$$\Pr(X > Y + 12~\text{or}~Y > X + 12) = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot 18 \cdot 18 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 18 \cdot 18}{30 \cdot 30} = \frac{324}{900} = \frac{9}{25}$$
You were trying to compute $\Pr(Y > X + 12)$.  As stated above, this is the region in the shaded triangle in the upper left corner of the diagram, which is bounded above by the line $Y = 30$ and bounded below by the line $Y = X + 18$.  These are the limits of integration for $Y$.  For his fiancee to arrive more than $12$ minutes later than he does, he must arrive in the first $18$ minutes.  Hence, the limits of integration for $X$ are $0$ and $18$.  Hence, 
$$\Pr(Y > X + 12) = \frac{1}{900}\int_{0}^{18}\int_{X + 18}^{30} dYdX$$
Since the situation is symmetric with respect to $X$ and $Y$, $\Pr(X > Y + 12) = \Pr(Y > X + 12)$.  Hence, the probability that one member of the couple arrives more than $12$ minutes later than the other is 
$$\Pr(X > Y + 12~\text{or}~Y > X + 12) = \Pr(X > Y + 12) + \Pr(Y > X + 12) = 2\Pr(Y > X + 12)$$